# Can’t start .exe file. Using Launch4j 3.12

Tags: java

I’m trying to start .exe file. But it doesn't open.

I use `Launch4j 3.12`

The jar file works from the command prompt: C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\Gracian\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar>java -jar EnglishTest.jar

Here is Launch4j log:

Version:    3.12
CmdLine:    C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\TheOracle.exe --l4j-debug
WOW64:      yes
Working dir:    C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar.
Java min ver:
Java max ver:
Bundled JRE:    jre1.8.0_211
Check launcher: C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\jre1.8.0_211\bin\javaw.exe (OK)
Main class: sample.Main
Info:       Classpath not defined.
Launcher:   C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\jre1.8.0_211\bin\javaw.exe
Launcher args:  -classpath "C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\TheOracle.exe" sample.Main
Args length:    154/32768 chars
Exit code:  0

Why the .exe file doesn’t start? How to find out the reason? Do I need to install a different jre version or what? Please help

Comment: Was there a warning message when you executed the packaging with launch4j ?

Comment: Only message in Launch4j 3.12:                                                                    Compiling resources
Linking
Wrapping
WARNING: Sign the executable to minimize antivirus false positives or use launching instead of wrapping.
Successfully created C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\Gracian\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\TheOracle.exe

Comment: You should not add the jre in the jar yourself, rather this job is done by launch4j. See the `<jre>` portion of the configuration file at http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html

Comment: Ok I deleted the jre from jar and wrote in Launch4j 3.12 in Min JRE version field: 1.8.0                                                                                                                         And now there is no message "This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted."                                        But the .exe file isn't starting

Comment: But the jar starts from command line: C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\Gracian\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar>java -jar EnglishTest.jar                                      Hmm..

Comment: When making the software, I had jre1.8.0_211                                                                           Now I have jdk-14.0.2                                                                                                 Do I need to download that old jre version?                                                                            How can  find it, if so?

Comment: Please note: linking to screen shots is really not appreciated here. Try to provide all relevant information as TEXT within your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is paragraph, to answer to your question. When running l4j, you have to provide the full path of a valid jre, it is explained in the l4j docs. Taken from http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html :

```
<jre>
    <path>bundled JRE path (%VAR%)</path>
    ...
</jre>
```

so for instance, if you already have a configured JAVA_HOME environment variable is configured, you could use

```
<jre>
    <path>%JAVA_HOME%</path>
    ...
</jre>
```

but this may be the default value, and maybe it has no value, so you could specify the path to a valid jre ( it can be a more recent jre than the one that was used to compile, but not an older one )

```
<jre>
    <path>C:\Program Files\Java\jre_1.1234</path>
</jre>
```

**EDIT**
In fact, the `%JREHOMEDIR%` is the default value. But the docs says that the path is not checked until the application is executed. I would probably try to assign a value to `%JREHOMEDIR%` using SystemPropertiesAdvanced

**SECOND EDIT**
I've re-downloaded the launch4j executables and tried with a small java app i already had. With the different steps of configuration, I tried with specifying a jre path and without specifying a jre path and both produced an exe that i am able to run. But then, if I specify a path that no longer exists i receive the message you describe [image]

So it's either you specify a valid jre path ( the path will have to be valid on each computer that the target app will be runned )

[image]

OR, you "only" specify a min version.
[image]

It is easier to produce the configuration file with graphical ui.
And then you have to re-reun the exe produdction with `launch4jc.exe c:\Users\...\newly_saved_config.xml"`

**THIRD EDIT**
Answering your comment on my answer:
You'd have to add the main class to the MANIFEST.MF of the jar.
You do so by adding a line to the manifest file located under the META-INF directory. If you compile with maven you can include a line in the pom.xml that adds the Main class to the manifest.
For more details, you can read this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

You are almost there !

Comment: I added launch4j log. The .exe file still doesn't start..

Comment: Does your jar now contains a manifest file ? if yes, what does the console says on exe startup ? If no, you can add a manifest that looks like this: 

    `Manifest-Version: 1.0`
    `Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver`
    `Created-By: Apache Maven`
    `Built-By: simon`
    `Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_232`
    `Main-Class: MyMainJavaClassName`

Where the MyMainJavaClassName.java contains a method that has signature `public static void main(String [] args)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I installed different versions of jdk and jre. Now .exe file works!!! Thanks for trying to help me!